# Error Mapping HDFS files to an external drive

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I want to make a folder in hadoop-2.7.3 that physically resides on an external (usb-thumb) drive, the idea being that any file that I -copyFromLocal, will reside on the thumb drive.  Similarly any output files from hadoop also goes to the external drive:

```
mkdir /media/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
hdfs dfs -mkdir /media/usb/test  
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /media/source/input.data /media/usb/test
hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-*.jar \
     -input  /media/usb/test/input.data \
     -output /media/usb/test/output.data
```

But I get no such file/folder error when trying to make the folder above.. it works only if I make the folders local to hadoop:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /test  
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /media/source/input.data /test
```

Unfortunately this places the input data file onto the same drive as the hadoop install, which is nearly full.   Is there a way to make/map an HDFS folder so that it's reads/writes from an drive other than the hadoop drive?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible! It defies the whole idea of distributed storage and processing.

When you do a **`copyFromLocal` the file goes from your local onto a HDFS location** (which hadoop manages). You may add your new drive as a HDFS DataNode but may not mandate a file to move to it.

If space is your only constraint then add the new drive as a datanode and re-balance the cluster.

---

Once the new node is added and datanode service is started on it, balance the cluster using:

```
hdfs balancer
      [-threshold <threshold>]
      [-policy <policy>]
      [-exclude [-f <hosts-file> | <comma-separated list of hosts>]]
      [-include [-f <hosts-file> | <comma-separated list of hosts>]]
      [-idleiterations <idleiterations>]
```

Refer: [HDFS Balancer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#balancer)

Comment: So it sounds like it is possible but I first must specify the usb path as the datanode in hdfs-site.xml.    After formatting it (hdfs 'hdfs namenode -format), then any 'dfs -mkdir' and '-copyFromLocal' commands will be using the external drive, no?    Or are you saying this won't work due to differences in filesystem (i.e. FAT32 thumb drive)?

Comment: @ben it doesn't work like that. First install hadoop on the new drive _(on whatever OS)_, then copy configs to it and then start that data node. Post this you have to just re-balance the cluster. **Note: your OS doesn't matter, the nodes must be configured to be on the same hadoop cluster and that's all matters.**